# How to change the default bash shell size Fedora 20

Tags: bash, shell, fedora

Ok I am tired of Googling and not finding a definitive answer. All I want to do is change the default shell size on a per user basis but for each shell instance they open and I want to do this from command line as admin user/root.

I am thinking I need to put something in the ~./.bash_profile, .profile, or .bashrc file in the users home folder but I don't know what to add or where to put it.  So if I wanted to make the default shell always open at 105x30 for user A what would I need to do?

Comment: The window size has nothing to do with the shell. You need to change the settings for the terminal program the user uses, which if it's not you, may not be the terminal program you expect.

Comment: So how can I do that on a per user basis? I'm assuming if I change the global config for bash it would affect all users, which is not what I want but if its the only way.....

Comment: You cannot change the window size by doing anything with the bash configuration. There is no reliable way to always set the terminal size you want, if a different user decides he/she wants something different (i.e. something you didn't expect).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys - found out that by changing the gnome-terminal.desktop file in /usr/share/applications you can set it to whatever you like and its:

1) on a per user basis

2) persists through logouts/reboots.

You can run something like this:

```
sed -i s/^Exec=gnome-terminal/"Exec=gnome-terminal --geometry=105x58+720+50"/ /usr/share/applications/gnome-terminal.desktop
```

Thanks to Tecton over at the Fedora Forums for this solution! Keep in mind this is only for Fedora 20 using the gnome terminal but may work with any distro using gnome terminal. YMMV